# Are there stats for the Antaran Hero at the end of Master of Orion II?

Tags: master-of-orion-2

When you attack Antares in Master of Orion II, a scan of the Star Fortress in orbit of the planet shows the face of an Antaran. Is this a hero? If so, are his stats and abilities known?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [a Master of Orion II fan site](http://lordbrazen.blogspot.ca/2005/08/master-of-orion-ii-ship-officers.html):

> **Xyphys the Antaran Warrior**
>   Starting Exp: 1000, Commands the Antaran Star Fortress
>
> Fighter Pilot* +7 (+7 to 8 per level)
>   Helmsman* +7 (+7 to 8 per level)
>   Ordnance* +7 (+7 to 8 per level)
>   Security* +3 (+3 per level)
>   Weapons* +7 (+7 to 8 per level)

Comment: Well done. I googled for the longest time without success.